# Combine result of two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select, distinct, union

I have two tables

```
TABLE_A
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| bid   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| uid   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and

```
TABLE_B
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| bid   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
| uid   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
+-------+------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I want to select bid from both tables when the uid = 123;
Note: each table has about 15 results and some exists in both tables, I need to select distinctively.
so I tried this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ta.bid, 
                tb.bid 
FROM   table_a AS ta 
       JOIN table_b AS tb using (uid) 
WHERE  uid = 123;
```

And I got the wrong answer obviously. Why is it getting 150+ results instead of 30?

Comment: UNION? Failing that, consider providing proper DDLs and/or an sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET

Comment: If you want to get results from both tables that match `uid = 123` ?

Comment: Oh yeah totally forgot union :) please post it as the answer so I can accept it

Comment: @DibyenduDutta Yes thats what I want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT bid FROM TABLE_A WHERE uid = 123
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT bid FROM TABLE_B WHERE uid = 123
```

**OR**

```
SELECT DISTINCT bid 
FROM (SELECT bid FROM TABLE_A WHERE uid = 123
      UNION 
      SELECT bid FROM TABLE_B WHERE uid = 123
     ) AS A
```

Comment: I just need to make sure the end result does not contain any duplicates, adding distinct to each select wont work since I need it to be for the result

Comment: Could you please explain why do I have to alias the derived table?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ta.bid, 
       tb.bid 
FROM   table_a AS ta, 
       table_b AS tb 
WHERE  ta.uid = tb.uid 
       AND ta.uid = 123 
GROUP  BY ta.bid, 
          tb.bid
```

Second Method would be

```
SELECT ta.bid, 
       tb.bid 
FROM   table_a AS ta 
       INNER JOIN table_b AS tb 
               ON ( ta.uid = tb.uid ) 
                  AND ( ta.uid = 123 )
```

Comment: I need to specify the uid, update your answer please :)

Comment: Updated with the Matching Condition UID

Comment: The bid has to match and I have to specify the uid, like uid = 123

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
select tb1.bid, tb2.bid from TABLE_A  AS tb1  , TABLE_B  AS tb2 
where tb1.bid = tb2.bid 
AND tb1.bid = 123
group by tb1.bid
```

Comment: It has to be distinct

Comment: Well happy that you got your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to do a union, filtering the remaining results

```
SELECT bid 
FROM   table_a 
WHERE  uid = 123 
UNION 
SELECT bid 
FROM   table_b 
WHERE  uid = 123
```

Here's a fiddle to help you visualize the result: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/27eea5/4

Answer (score 1):

USE UNION
Its Used to Combines the result of two or more SELECT statements.

```
SELECT  bid FROM TABLE_A WHERE uid = 123
UNION 
SELECT  bid FROM TABLE_B WHERE uid = 123
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
SELECT DISTINCT bid 
FROM   (SELECT bid 
        FROM   table_a 
        WHERE  uid = 123 
        UNION 
        SELECT bid 
        FROM   table_b 
        WHERE  uid = 123) AS temp;
```